# Completely lost, help please on setters and getters

Tags: java, setter, getter

Okay so the main method was given to me in my book. I just have to work with setters and getters, and create a determineTypeOfStudent method. The goal is to display their name, age, and then the grade they are probably in.

The errors that appear are as following:

```
System.out.println("Age ", + student1.getAge());
```

It says no suitable  method found for println(String,int) followed by a paragraph of things saying "not applicable"

```
System.out.println("Type of Student: " + student1.determineTypeOfStudent());
```

This one says "method determineTypeOfStudent in class Student cannot be applied to given types;
required: int
found: non arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in lenght

surround with ...

### introduce ...

Then these two:

```
System.out.println("Type of Student: " + student2.determineTypeOfStudent());

System.out.println("Type of Student: " + student1.determineTypeOfStudent());
```

Who are the same as the previous.

I'm pretty new to this stuff, so I'd appreciate it if you guys corrected me and gave me an explanation thanks.

```
public class StudentClient {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student student1 = new Student("Bob", 15);
    Student student2 = new Student("Jan", 13);

    System.out.println("Name: " + student1.getName());
    System.out.println("Age ", + student1.getAge());
    System.out.println("Type of Student: " + student1.determineTypeOfStudent());

    System.out.println("\n" + student2.fullString());
    System.out.println("Type of Student: " + student2.determineTypeOfStudent());

    student1.setName("Ted");
    student1.setAge(35);

    System.out.println("\n" + student1.fullString());
    System.out.println("Type of Student: " + student1.determineTypeOfStudent());
}
```

-------CLASS FILE-----------

```
public class Student {
private String studentName;
private int studentAge;

public Student(String newName, int newAge) {
    setName(newName);
    setAge(newAge);
}

public void setName(String newName) {
    studentName = newName;
}

public String getName() {
    return studentName;
}

public void setAge(int newAge) {
    if (newAge > 0) {
        studentAge = newAge;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Age cannot be less than zero");
    }
}       

public int getAge() {
    return studentAge;    
}

public String fullString() {
    return (studentName + studentAge);
}

public static String determineTypeOfStudent(int studentAge){
    if (studentAge > 0 || studentAge <= 4)
        return "Preschool";
    else if (studentAge == 5)
        return "Kindergarten";
    else if (studentAge >= 6 || studentAge <= 10)
        return "Elementary School";
    else if (studentAge >= 11 || studentAge <= 13)
        return "Middle School";
    else if (studentAge >= 14 || studentAge <= 17)
        return "High School";
    else if (studentAge >= 18)
        return "College";

    else
        return "Invalid";
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change :

```
System.out.println("Age ", + student1.getAge());
```

to

```
System.out.println("Age " + student1.getAge());
```

`System.out.println` takes a single argument.

As for `determineTypeOfStudent` - you call it with no arguments, but it is declare to accept a single int argument. In addition, you should consider whether you really want that method to be static.

Comment: Oops, that comma was a typo, thanks for catching that. If not static what should it be and why?

Comment: @DonaldNeal I don't know what `determineTypeOfStudent` should do, but you call it for a specific student instance - `student1.determineTypeOfStudent()`. If it will contains logic that uses data from that instance, it can't be static. Just remove the static keyword. If it doesn't depend on any Student instance, keep it static, but call it like a static method - Student.determineTypeOfStudent() - which makes it clear this is a static method.

Comment: DetermineTypeOfStudent method returns the most likely level of
schooling for the student.
o Preschool (age 0 – 4)
o Kindergarten (age 5)
o Elementary School (age 6-10)
o Middle School (age 11-13)
o High School (age 14-17)
o College (age 18 & up)

Comment: Ah yay actually, I fixed it all. But my else if statements were wrong as well, but I changed them to &&'s instead of ||'s and everything ran perfectly! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

The first one isn't good because println only accepts one argument. The second one doesn't work because you can't add a String and an int. You should first call print on the String, and then println on the int.

```
System.out.print("Age ");
System.out.println(student1.getAge());
```